# aws s3 sync with metadata possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to regularily backup an S3 bucket (total size ~20GB, ~200k files) to a local filesystem.

`aws s3 sync s3://... ./data` looks to be good for this task but AFAIK does *not* copy metadata to the filesystem, which is bad because the files in the backup store *important* metadata (mainly, if the file is gzip compressed or not).

Can `aws s3` **or any similar tool** copy metadata to the local file system (for example to [xattr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#Linux) or a separate "metadata database")?

Comment: s3fs seems to be able to do that, but I could not get it running

Comment: And `gsutil rsync -P` preverses POSIX attributes